# Integer side length right triangles with area = perimeter

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

How many right triangles with integer side lengths (up to congruence) are there with the property that the area of the triangle is the same as the perimeter?

I found that $5, 12, 13$ has both an area and perimeter of 30 but I'm not sure if there are any more of them.

Comment: $(6,8,10)$ is another.

Comment: thanks, is that the only other one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are looking for $a,b\in\mathbb N$ such that $ab = 2a+2b+2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. After some manipulation, we have $$4a^2+4b^2=a^2b^2-4ab(a+b)+4a^2+8ab+4b^2$$$$a^2b^2-4ab(a+b-2)=0$$$$a^2b^2=4ab(a+b-2)$$$$ab=4(a+b-2)$$$$ab-4a-4b+16=8$$$$(a-4)(b-4)=8$$

So, there are only two possibilities as there are only two possible pairs of $(a-4,b-4)$: $(1,8)$ and $(2,4)$, which correspond to $(5,12,13)$ and $(6,8,10)$, respectively.

Comment: There are actually infinetly many solutions to this system, of course if we add the fact that this MUST be pithagorean triplets, then we have only two cases

Comment: @Samorales Look at the beginning of my answer, and the domain to which $a,b$ belong.

Comment: I did not pay attention to that, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

The answer also falls directly out of the canonical formula for Pythagorean triples: $x=m^2-n^2;\ y=2mn;\ z=m^2+n^2$.

Accordingly, $P=m^2-n^2+2mn+m^2+n^2=2m(m+n)$ and $A=\frac{1}{2}(m^2-n^2)(2mn)=mn(m+n)(m-n)$

$P=A \Rightarrow 2m(m+n)=mn(m+n)(m-n)$. Removing identical factors, $2=n(m-n)$

Since $2$ is prime, the only solutions are $m,n=3,1$ and $m,n=3,2$, which yield the triples identified by the previous responders: $(6,8,10)\ \text{and}\ (5,12,13)$

Answer (score 1):

To solve this question we need to go to the equations, notice that the area of a right triangle is denoted as:

$$\frac{a b}{2}$$
Where $a$ and $b$ are the legs of the triangle. On the other side, the perimeter of this triangle is 
$$a+b+c$$
Where $c$ is the hypotenuse of the same triangle.
We can draw a relationship between c, a and b because by the pitagorean theorem we now that
$$c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
and now we can group both equation with this last equality to have the following
$$\frac{a b}{2}=a+b+c$$
$$\frac{a b}{2}=a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
After some basic algebraic manipulation we get the following expression

$$a=\frac{4 (b-2)}{b-4}$$
If we let $b=5$, then $a=12$ and by pithagorean theorem $c=13$

Comment: You have to be a bit careful about dividing by expressions like $b-4$.

Comment: Sure, since this is a fractional expression, we can not use values suech as b=4

Comment: a has to be an integer, so you should consider when does b-4 divide 4, and when does it divide b-2. A quick think quickly eliminates all candidates for 4 as it is small, and in fact will give you the 2nd solution. Now can you prove from this that these are the only solutions?

Answer (score 1):

We use the parameterization
$$ (a,b,c) = ( s^2 - t^2, 2st, s^2 + t^2) ,$$where $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime positive integers of different parities. We then want
$$ st(s^2 - t^2) = 2( s^2  -t^2 + 2st + s^2 + t^2) = 4s(s+t) . $$As $s$ and $s+t$ are nonzero, we may divide to obtain
$$ t(s-t) = 4 .$$Since $t$ and $s-t$ must be relatively prime, we must either have $t=1$ or $t=4$. This gives the possibilities $(5,1)$ and $(5,4)$ for $(s,t)$. But $s$ and $t$ must have different parities, so our only possible solution is $(5,4)$. This gives us the Pythagorean triple $\boxed{(9,40,41)}$, which indeed satisfies the problem's conditions: the area of the corresponding triangle is $180$, and the perimeter is $90$.